# ksh loop putting results of file into variable

Tags: while-loop, ksh

I'm not sure the best way to handle this, I'm guessing it's using a while loop.  I have a .txt file with a set of numbers ( these numbers can change based on another script that runs ) 
ex:

```
0
36
41
53
60
```

Each number is on it's own line. For each number I want to get that number and execute a script using it. So in this example I would call a script to stop database 0, after that completes call a script to stop database 36 and so on until it's complete with all numbers in the list.

1) Is a while loop the best way to handle this?
2) I'm having trouble trying to determine what the [[condition]] needs to be to get each number 1 at a time, where can i find some additional help on this?

```
    while [[ condition ]] ; do
    command1 
    done
```

For testing purposes the file that contains all the numbers is test.txt. The script that will execute is a python script - "amgr.py stop (number from test.txt)"

Comment: while read -r line ; do
        echo "$line"
done<test.txt

Is it as simple as $line = the number each time?

Comment: yes, you've answered your own question. You can post that as an answer and then after X hrs accept it to gain reputation points (if you care). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this method to give me the results i was looking for.

```
while read -r line ; do
amgr.py stop $line
done<test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler way:

```
cat test.txt | xargs amgr.py stop
```

this will get each line of your file, and then put it as an extra parameter for your `amgr.py`:

```
amgr.py stop 0
amgr.py stop 36
and so on..
```